# The method clone() from the type Object is not visible. Extend solves it

Tags: java, clone, extend

```
public class Human extends Main implements Cloneable{
    public String name;
    public Human(){};
    public Human(String input){
        this.name = input;
    }
}

import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main{
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      try{
         Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
         String input = in.next();

         Human h1 = new Human(input);
         Human h2 = (Human) h1.clone();

         System.out.println("Human original " + h1.name);
         System.out.println("Human clone " + h2.name);
         in.close();
      } catch(Exception e){}
   }
}
```

Why does the Human class have to extend Main? If not, Human h2 = (Human)h1.clone() will give an error "The method clone() from the type Object is not visible"

What's the point for Human class to extend Main? Human class doesn't need to inherit anything from Main class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Object.clone();` is protected, meaning it's visible to subclasses and classes in the same package. If you don't extend `Main`, `clone()` isn't visible since `Human` inherits it from `Object` (not visible to `Main`). However extending `Main` means that `clone()` is inherited from `Main`, which is in the same package, making it accessible.

However normally you would implement a `public` version of `clone()`, even if to just call `super.clone();` in it.

Answer (score 0):

`Cloneable` and `clone()` are legacy design mistakes from very early versions of Java; don't use them.

If you want to create a "clone" of an instance, provide a copy constructor, and copy the fields yourself:

```
public Human(Human other) {
  this.name = other.name;
}
```

There is an item in *Effective Java* which describes the problem with clone in detail, and why you should avoid it (also [described here](http://www.artima.com/intv/bloch13.html)).